# Space complexity of list creation

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, space-complexity

Could someone explain me what is the space complexity of beyond program, and why is it?

```
def is_pal_per(str):

s = [i for i in str]
nums = [0] * 129

for i in s:
    nums[ord(i)] += 1

count = 0

for i in nums:
    if i != 0 and i / 2 == 0:
        count += 1

print count

if count > 1:
    return False
else:
    return True
```

Actually, i'm interested in this lines of code. How does it influence on space complexity of above program?

```
s = [i for i in str]
```

`nums = [0] * 129`

Comment: s is of the same size as your string (number of chars). For big strings, that's bigger than nums, for small strings, it's smaller. What's exactly the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unclear where you're having trouble with this.  **s** is simply a list of individual characters in **str**.  The space consumption is **len(s)**.

**nums** is a constant size, dominated by the **O(N)** term.

Is this code you wrote, or has this been handed to you?  The programming style is highly *not* "Pythonic".

---

As for your code, start with this collapse:

```
count = 0

for char in str:
    val = ord[char] + 1
    if abs(val) == 1:
        count += 1

print count

return count == 0
```

First, I replaced your single-letter variables (**s** => **char**; **i** => **val**).  Then I cut out *most* of the intermediate steps, leaving in a couple to help you read the code.  Finally, I used a straightforward Boolean value to return, rather than the convoluted statement of the original.

I did *not* use Python's counting methods -- that would shorten the function even more.  By the way, do you *have* to print the count of unity values, or do you just need the Boolean return?  If it's just the return value, you can make this even shorter.

Comment: i have entry level python skills. That's why code style is not god for python programmers. Could you tell what is not 'Pythonic' in code above? What about second line of code, where i alocated 'nums' list?

Comment: On the subject of 'Pythonic'-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011078/what-does-pythonic-mean

Answer (score 0):

You have found the only two lines that allocate memory:

```
s = [i for i in str]
nums = [0] * 129
```

The first grows linearly with `len(str)`, the second is a constant. Therefore, the space complexity of your function is O(N), N=length of `str`.