# how to find the avg in nested lists using for/while loop in python

Tags: python

```
def average_list(M):
'''(list of list of int) -> list of float

Return a list of floats where each float is the average of 
the corresponding list in the given list of lists.

>>> average_list([[4, 6], [5, 5]])
[5.0, 5.0]

'''
L = []

for item in M:
    for i in range(len(item)):
        avg = sum(item[i])/len(item[i])
        L.append(avg)
return L
```

error: 
average_list([[4, 6], [5, 5]])
Traceback (most recent call last):
    avg = sum(item[i])/len(item[i])
builtins.TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

I want to know how to fix it, thanks a lot!
And any other way to do in while loop?

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do in your for loop? All you need is to iterate over `M` by value, not by index. This line `for i in range(len(item)):` is causing your error. Your inner for loop is not needed.

```
def average_list(M):
    L = []
    for item in M:
        avg = sum(item)/len(item)
        L.append(avg)
    return L
```

But you should Use list comprehension instead. In my opinion, it would be the most canonical way to solve your problem, not to mention the most ["Pythonic"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011078/what-does-pythonic-mean):

```
>>> def average_list(M):
        return [sum(sublist)/len(sublist) for sublist in M]

>>> average_list([[4, 6], [5, 5]])
[5.0, 5.0]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that `item[i]` is a single element, which you cannot `sum` or `len`. You did not need that inner loop and for loops would be preferred over while loops because you have a finite collection.

If using Python3, you can use the mean function, and map that over the list of lists

```
from statistics import mean

def average_list(M):
    return list(map(mean, M))
```

Borrowed from [Finding the average of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039961/finding-the-average-of-a-list)

Comment: I only can use the for loop or while loop to do this.

Comment: That's fine. I already explained the reason for the error. I think the source code for `map` uses a for loop, so if anyone complains, just say that ;)

Answer (score 0):

in python 3:

```
lst=[[4, 6], [5, 5]]
list(map(lambda x: sum(x)/len(x), lst))
Out[104]: [5.0, 5.0]
```

or in python 2:

```
from __future__ import division
lst=[[4, 6], [5, 5]]
map(lambda x: sum(x)/len(x), lst)
Out[104]: [5.0, 5.0]
```