# Pythonic way to flush() both sys.stdout & sys.stderr

Tags: python

So I have a python script which I'm redirecting **stdout AND  stderr** to a file. I need to flush this file periodically. What is the best way to achieve this

```
sys.stdout = sys.stderr = open('location/log.txt', 'w')
```

Do we have to do it in two separate steps?

```
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.stderr.flush()
```

I'm doing this as i'm constantly reading from this file to check for updates.

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is ["**pythonic**"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011078/what-does-pythonic-mean).

Answer (score 2):

If you've aliased `sys.stderr` and `sys.stdout` to the same open file handle, you only need to flush one of them; they're the same file object, so flushing one is flushing "all" ("all" being the only existing file object).