# Add an extra letter to each line in existing file from a list in Python

Tags: python, file

I have a file which has only + and - in 1 line and there are multiple lines.
So basically file is as below.

```
-++++
+----
+++++
```

and I have a script which does health check of some websites and extending these lines. So, every line above means another website from a list. (e.g: ["example.com", "google.com", "test.com"]

My script runs every 5minutes and everytime it runs I am adding plus or minus depends on website's availability.

I tried somethings like using `readlines` method but it returns me `['-++++\n', '+----\n', '+++++\n']`.
I am a bit stuck with overriding same file with new value both because I don't know what's best way and because of these new lines characters in the returned list from readlines method.

What would be your suggestion for solving this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appending characters to each line in a txt file with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47276506/appending-characters-to-each-line-in-a-txt-file-with-python)

Comment: Can you share your current code? The newline issue is simple to solve, by the way, there is at least one very popular question on the subject here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [rstrip()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/how-can-i-remove-a-trailing-newline) on each element in the list and then add a + or -

You then should be able to just set lines in the file equal to elements in the list.

EDIT: something that could be giving you trouble is that in python strings are immutable, meaning any time you make a change you have to "re-set" the variable.

IE

`x = "test string\n" 
x.rstrip() #prints "test string"`

x is still equal to "test string\n" though, you need to do this

`x = "test string\n" 
x = x.rstrip() #sets x to "test string"`