# Formatting files function is writing unecessary "," when it's not supposed to

Tags: python

I have a function to create and write some info to a .txt file. I have to write it like this:

```
11:13, Andrej Hlavac, Zdenka Sedlak
```

But instead, I get:

```
11:13, Andrej Hlavac, Zdenka Sedlak,
```

The function that writes this output is:

```
def write_assignments_file(assignments, header, file_name):
        header[1]=str(dateTime.date(header[3],header[1],5))                  
        header='\n'.join(header)                                
        timetable=open(file_name,'w')                   
        timetable.write(str(header)+'\n')
        timetable.write('Timetable:'+'\n')
        for i in range(len(assignments)):
                for re in assignments[i]:
                        timetable.write(str(re)+', ')
                timetable.write('\n')
        timetable.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

You're current code adds a `', '` after every element so of course there will be one at the end. The `str.join(sep, it)` method only puts the `sep` string *in between* each element of `it`.

So replace

```
for re in assignments[i]:
    timetable.write(str(re)+', ')
```

with

```
 timetable.write(', '.join(map(str, assignments[i])))
```

---

For the record, never do

```
for i in range(len(assignments)):
     do_something(assignments[i])
```

instead do

```
for assignment in assignments:
     timetable.write(', '.join(map(str, assignment)))
```

If you need the indices of `assignments`, use [`enumerate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171558/what-does-enumerate-mean).

Comment: I'm curious why you should never do `for i in range(len(x))`, could you elaborate more on that?

Comment: Well you can, but it's not very [pythonic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011078/what-does-pythonic-mean). It screams "I've come from another language and don't really know what I'm doing in python". 

While it's often necessary in say, C++, to do `for (int i = 0; i != a.size(); i++){f(a[i]);}`, in python it's far more clear what you're doing when you do `for elem in a: f(elem)` or `for index, elem in enumerate(a): f(index, elem)`. There's also the issue that python iterators are commonly generators, which have no `__len__` method, so `len(gen)` will fail. Try `len(zip(x,y))`