# Is it pythonic to make two type conversions as in list(str(my_integer))?

Tags: python

I want to convert an integer, say

```
my_integer=1412323
```

to a list of chars

```
['1','4',...]
```

The quickest way I can think of is

```
list(str(my_integer))
```

Are there any pythonic objections to doing this?

Comment: Looks fine to me... but it really depends on what you plan to do with the `list`.

Comment: If the only reason you need a list is for iteration, the `str` value itself is already an iterable consisting of the individual characters.

Comment: YES - [here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25011492/9396198)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed very pythonic, and it is quite fast. Let's compare it with another method. Compare it with a list comprehension (which is also considered to be pythonic):

```
%%timeit
[x for x in str(my_integer)]
```

> 883 ns ± 32.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

And with your propostion we get :

```
%%timeit
list(str(my_integer))
```

> 743 ns ± 33.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

As a general guideline I would say that a pythonic way is most of the time concise and loopless. And if you want to be sure, benchmark it using %%timeit with other "classical" methods.

Answer (score 5):

Yes that is a completely fine way of doing it! If you just need to iterate through each character of the string though you don't need to convert into a `list` as a `str` is an iterable. So you can do:

```
for num in str(my_integer):
    print(num)
```

Comment: I want to iterate over it, but I only want to go halfway up the string, and then I also want to go backwards on it, and I can't think of a list comprehension over the str to do so.