# Can a Python nested function variable be used in other nested functions?

Tags: python, function, scope, encapsulation, local-variables

I am currently working on a simple calculator program and I have run into a problem with taking data from a nested function and using it in another nested function.

Here is the portion of my code that this problem relates to:

```py
def func():
  
  def func1():
    a = float(input("Enter first number: "))
    b = float(input("Enter second number: "))
  
  def func2():
    print(f"{a}, {b}")

  func1()
  func2()

func()
```

As you can see, `func()` is called which calls `func1()` and `func2()`. However, running this program results in `NameError: name 'a' is not defined` with an error reference line pointing towards the body of `func2()`.

I know it is not possible to access `a, b` within `func2()` as they are only defined within `func1()`, but I cannot use the `nonlocal` statement as according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement):

> 'names listed in a nonlocal statement ... must refer to pre-existing bindings in an enclosing scope.'

and `func1()` does not enclose `func2()`.

More so, I am trying to avoid using the `global` statement or defining `a` and `b` in `func()` because it seems to be poor practise in any programming language ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59330578/how-to-avoid-using-global-variables)) and could lead to unintended side-effects later on in my program's development.

Is there any way to declare `a` and `b` as usable and modifiable anywhere within `func()`, whilst still defining it in `func1`?

Comment: You could return a and b values from func1 and pass them as parameters on func2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to return them in func1 and pass the results to func2

```
def func1():
    a = float(input("Enter first number: "))
    b = float(input("Enter second number: "))
    return a, b
```

Then,

```
def func2(a, b):
    print(f"{a}, {b}")
```

And then when you call the functions you assign variables a and b to the result of func1 and pass them as parameters to func2,

```
a,b = func1()
func2(a, b)
```

You could initialize the variables in the scope of func but it is better to handle them as the return of the function, it easier to keep track of the algorithm that way.

Answer (score 1):

That's problem of scope.

You have 2 possibilities to make it work:

**1. Return `a` and `b` in `func1`, and call `func1` in `func2`:**

```
def func():
  
    def func1():
      a = float(input("Enter first number: "))
      b = float(input("Enter second number: "))

      return (a,b)
  
    def func2():
      a,b = func1()
      print(f"{a}, {b}")

  
    func2()

func()
```

**2. Define `func2` in `func1`, and call `func2` in `func1` after its declaration, and call `func1` in `func`, after its declaration:**

```
def func():
  
    def func1():
      a = float(input("Enter first number: "))
      b = float(input("Enter second number: "))


  
      def func2():
        print(f"{a}, {b}")

  
      func2()
    func1()

func()
```