# How do i use lists from other functions?

Tags: python, function

Still learning python3 and im currently creating a domino game. I'm making progress so far but i haven't been working with functions at all.

**My question is:** How do i get the domino_stock_set into my split_stones function so i can split it up?

Seems like a dumb question but i googled half an hour and couldn't find anything that would work. I tried anything so at this point i might have several erros in the script.

```
import random

random_hand = random.randint(0, 7)
random_sixseven = random.randint(6,7)



def stock_set():
    global domino_stock_set
    domino_stock_set = []
    for i in range(0, 7):
        for j in range(i, 7):
            domino_stock_set.append([i, j])
    random.shuffle(domino_stock_set)
    
    print()
    print("…ᘛ⁐̤ᕐᐷ  -Stock Set-  …ᘛ⁐̤ᕐᐷ")
    print(domino_stock_set)
    print()
    return domino_stock_set



def split_stones(domino_stock_set, wanted_parts=1):
    length = len(domino_stock_set)
    return [ domino_stock_set[i*length // wanted_parts: (i+1)*length // wanted_parts] 
             for i in range(wanted_parts) ]

print("==============P L A Y E R==================")
print(split_stones(domino_stock_set, wanted_parts = random_sixseven))

print("=============C O M P U T E R===============")
print(split_stones(domino_stock_set, wanted_parts = random_sixseven))



stock_set()
split_stones()
```

Comment: it still doesn't work. could you explain how?

Comment: im getting this error now: length = len(domino_stock_set)
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Answer (score 0):

I would just google for something like "python function arguments". Then you will get results such as e.g. [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_function_arguments.asp).

To apply it to your example:

```py
domino_stock_set = []
split_stones(domino_stock_set)
```

Furthermore, try to avoid using `global` variables, see e.g. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59330578/how-to-avoid-using-global-variables). If you use `domino_stock_set` as a global variable you do not even need to pass it to any function because that variable would be available globally.

Comment: i tried this but for some reason it did not work.