# Flatten a list of lists containing single strings to a list of ints

Tags: python

i have list with lists of strings looks like

```
allyears
#[['1916'], ['1919'], ['1922'], ['1912'], ['1924'], ['1920']]
```

i need to have output like this:

```
#[1916, 1919, 1922, 1912, 1924, 1920]
```

have been try this:

```
for i in range(0, len(allyears)): 
    allyears[i] = int(allyears[i])
```

but i have error

```
>>> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

Comment: You are looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists

Comment: `int(allyears[i][0])`, or simply this: `[int(item[0]) for item in allyears]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
allyears = [int(i[0]) for i in allyears]
```

Because all the elements in your `allyears` is a list which has ony one element, so I get it by `i[0]`

The error is because ypu can't convert a `list` to an `int`

Comment: If there is only one item in nested list then one can also do it without indexing: `[int(*item) for item in allyears]`

Answer (score 6):

You're very close, you just need to take the first (and only) element of `allyears[i]` before doing the `int` conversion:

```
for i in range(0, len(allyears)): 
    allyears[i] = int(allyears[i][0])
```

Alternatively, you could do this in one line using a list comprehension:

```
allyears = [int(l[0]) for l in allyears]
```

Answer (score 5):

if you want a simple `for` loop you also may use `enumerate` built-in function and unpack your inner list:

```
for i, [n] in  enumerate(allyears): 
    allyears[i] = int(n)
```

---

you can use  a list comprehension:

```
allyears = [int(e) for l in allyears for e in l]
```

also, you can use `itertools.chain`

```
from itertools import chain

list(map(int, chain.from_iterable(allyears)))
```

output:

```
[1916, 1919, 1922, 1912, 1924, 1920]
```

the last 2 solutions will work also if in your inner lists you have more than one element

Answer (score 2):

You need to access individual elements of the list instead of lists itself.

Try:

```
for i in range(0, len(allyears)): 
    allyears[i] = int(allyears[i][0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
allyears = [['1916'], ['1919'], ['1922'], ['1912'], ['1924'], ['1920']]

out = []
for i in range(0, len(allyears)): 
    out.append(int(allyears[i][0]))

print (out)
```

Answer (score 0):

You tried this:

```
for i in range(0, len(allyears)): 
    allyears[i] = int(allyears[i])
```

and got the error

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

The next thing you should have tried is:

```
for i in range(0, len(allyears)): 
    print(allyears[i])
```

And you would have seen that you are looping through these values:

```
['1916']
['1919']
['1922']
```

etc.

Those cannot be converted to int using `int()`, because those are lists. You should get the only element of those lists using the `[0]` index like this:

```
>>> for i in range(0, len(allyears)): 
...    print(allyears[i][0])
1916
1919
1922...
```

And now you know how to correct your original code:

```
for i in range(0, len(allyears)): 
    allyears[i] = int(allyears[i][0])
```

---

The more [Pythonic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25011492/3310334) solution to your problem would use [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python):

```
allyears = [int(i[0]) for i in allyears]
```