# python index trouble "out of range"

Tags: python

I am fairly new to programming and I was wondering about some stuff within indexes.
I am trying to make a program that will type out words(I've got this part of the code working) but whenever I run the code with the index in I get this error: list index out of range.
I was wondering what this could mean.

thank you.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller 
keyboard = Controller()

x = 0

file = open("A:\\Development\\Languages\\Python\\Programs\\NEWTEXT.txt", "r" )

for line in file:
    fields = line.split(";")

while x < 340:
    song = fields[x]
    keyboard.type(song)
    x = x + 1 

file.close()

exit()
```

Comment: Please provide your input. In your code you basically just store the items of the last line in the file because you overwrite `fields` in every iteration in the `for` loop. Is that intentional? Where does the number 340 come from? Are there guaranteed to be 340 elements in the `fields` list? Check the traceback of the error that you are getting, it contains helpful information.

Comment: be sure that in your program there is 339 list in fields. You can check by printing and comment out rest

Comment: Index out of range usually means that you are trying to access an element of an iterable with an index that does not exist. I need more information on your code as mentioned to be able to diagnose the problem further.

Comment: The split command returns a List that you can iterate by using `for x in songs:`

Answer (score 0):

The split function returns a list. For example, in `fields = split("cat;dog;mouse")`, fields will be `["cat", "dog", "mouse"]`. In this case, there are 3 elements and you will get an out of bounds error if you try to access anything more than `fields[2]`.

In your case, your loop tries to access `fields[339]`, which will yield an error if your fields list has less than 340 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

Your error means that you are trying to read the content of a list beyond its length. For example, if I create a list with 3 items in it:

```py
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
this_does_not_exist = mylist[4]  # this is undefined -> IndexError
```

Trying to read the 4th element of a list with 3 items makes no sense, it is not defined, so python throws an `IndexError` at you.

In your case, your line that reads `songs = fields[x]` must be valid for all values of x up to 339, in other words, your `line` must have at least that many values for your code to work. You can get the length of your list with `len(fields)` instead of trying to guess it and then use it like this:

```py
for field in fields:
    # now field contains fields[x]
    keyboard.type(field)
```

This is considered more [pythonic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25011492/1138710) than using `while` like you did (which works as well, but requires you to write more code).

You can read more about `IndexError` in [the python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndexError).

Answer (score 0):

So assuming your NEWTEXT.txt file contents looks along the lines of:

```
jason;josh;christian;
```

you can modify your code to run independently of the number of elements like so:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller 
keyboard = Controller()

with open('A:\\Development\\Languages\\Python\\Programs\\NEWTEXT.txt') as f:
    content = f.read()

for song in content.split(';'):
    keyboard.type(song)
```

But I would recommend sharing the content of your file to have better suited answers.

Answer (score 0):

That error is caused when you tried to use a subscription of an index of the array, but the array is too small to supply that index, e.g:

```
l = [1,2,3,4] # The only available indexes are 0, 1, 2 and 3

print(l[6]) # This will trigger the index error
```

I'll add that opening and closing a file with like in your code is considered a bad practice, a context manager is generally more preferred.

In python, you can directly iterate through the element of an array, so you don't have to use and keep updating the index `x`:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller 

keyboard = Controller()

with open("A:\\Development\\Languages\\Python\\Programs\\NEWTEXT.txt", "r") as file:

    fields = [line.replace(";"," ") for line in file]

    for song in fields:
        keyboard.type(song)

exit()
```