# What does it mean for code to be "Pythonic"?

Tags: python

I've been working through the problems on LeetCode in Python and occasionally I'll see comments saying that someone's solution is "Pythonic". I guess it means that your code embodies the spirit of the language of Python, but what specific aspects and conventions does that refer to?

Comment: for example, `for i in range(len(lst))` is c style, `for item in lst` is Pythonic. and list comprehension is also Pythonic.

Comment: using the for clause is probably the most pythonic thing. Ima dditionseapping values as such a,b = b,a is considered pythonic

Comment: @FishballNooodles yes, that is a good example, using the old temporary variable construct *does work*, e.g. `temp = a; a = b; b = a` *works*, but it is more idiomatic to simply use `a, b = b, a`

Answer (score 0):

Well answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011078/what-does-pythonic-mean#:%7E:text=Pythonic%20means%20code%20that%20doesn,article%20from%20the%20other%20answers.)

But I would add that being pythonic is more than just to "Look like" python. Languages are designed in ways so that being some-language-ic makes the compiler/interpreter more efficient and less error-prone.

Comment: You should vote to close, not post a link to another question/answer as an answer

Comment: he doesn't have the previledge to vote to close, and nees some reputation to have that so answered.

Comment: @LeiYang Flagging as duplicate is possible with 15 reputation, I think.