# Slice up to last occurrence of character in string

Tags: python, slice

I want to slice string up to last occurrence of a specific character:

Example:

From the text "xxx.yyy.zzz" I want only "xxx.yyy"

From the text "xxx.xxx.yyy.xyzxzy" I want "xxx.xxx.yyy"

where I want to slice up to the last occurrence of ".".

Comment: `".".join(input.split(".")[:-1])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `str.rsplit`

```py
"xxx.yyy.zzz".rsplit('.', 1)[0]
'xxx.yyy'

"xxx.xxx.yyy.xyzxzy".rsplit('.', 1)[0]
'xxx.xxx.yyy'
```

Answer (score -1):

print(s[:-s[::-1].find('.') - 1])

Comment: s = 'your.string.123123.1312312.313'

Comment: This will work, but imagine seeing this line of code again in a year time: you'll have no idea what it does from just reading it.
It could be more 'pythonic': "clear, concise and maintainable", as nicely explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25011492/1282144