# Removing all lists in a list, that match a particular condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I am a beginner in Python and got a little stuck on a problem. It required me to remove all the items (in this particular case lists), that met a simple math requirement.
 Like for example: the sum of all elements is not equal to **n**.

---

So I tried this...

```
a_list = [[1, 1, 1], [3, 0, 0]]
for i in a_list:
    if sum(i) != 3:
        continue
    else:
        a_list.remove(i)
print(a_list)
```

---

But all I got was... `[[3, 0, 0]]`

---

Why did my program delete only the first object the met the condition, although the `for` loop is iterating through the whole list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify list entries during for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081217/how-to-modify-list-entries-during-for-loop)

Comment: Thanks, that's quite helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In brief, the reason you are getting the strange result is because you are iterating over your list while deleting its content.

#### Explanation

First time your loop runs, the internal iterator is pointing at the first element of the loop, which is `[1,1,1]`.

Since this element fails the initial condition, it is removed. When it is removed, the list internally will shift the next element (`[3,0,0]`) to the left to now occupy the position of the element that was removed.

Now the for-loop will attempt to go to the next element, but it now thinks that it has reached the end of the list, so it stops, and you are left with `[3,0,0]`.

#### Solution

Instead of modifying the original list, the more [pythonic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011078/what-does-pythonic-mean) solution is to create a new list consisting of just the elements you wanted, while ignoring the ones you don't want, and this is often accomplished by using [list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
a_list = [[1, 1, 1], [3, 0, 0]]
filtered_a_list = [elem for elem in a_list if sum(elem) != 3]
```

You can also do it without list-comprehension:

```
a_list = [[1, 1, 1], [3, 0, 0]]
filtered_a_list = []
for elem in a_list:
  if sum(elem) != 3:
    filtered_a_list.append(elem)
```

Comment: Ok. I get it now. Is there a way around it?

Comment: @Butyl yes, I just updated my answer with a solution

Answer (score -2):

General rule: Never ever modify a list while you iterate over it. It will f up the iteration. Always make copys (of the references or the objects). Also the if else is a bit useless as you could avoid one branch if you just inverted the condition.
What happens here is: Python deletes the first list, tries to access the list at index 1 but since it is now at index 0 it aborts the iteration thus leaving the second list in place.