# Modify the elements of a list inside a for loop (Python equivalent of Matlab code with a nested loop)

Tags: python, list, loops, matlab

I have the following Matlab code (adopted from Programming and Numerical Methods in MATLAB by Otto&Denier, page 75)

```
clear all
p = input('Enter the power you require: ');

points = p+2;
n = 1:points;
for N = n
     sums(N) = 0;
    for j = 1:N
        sums(N) = sums(N)+j^p;
    end
end
```

The output for 3 as the given value of p is the following list

```
>> sums
sums =
       1              9             36            100            225
```

I have written the following Python code (maybe not the most 'Pythonic way') trying to follow as much as possible Matlab instructions.

```
p = int(input('Enter the power you require: '))

points = p+2
n = range(points)
for N in range(1, len(n)+1):
    sums = [0]*N
    for index, item in list(enumerate(sums)):
        sums[index] = item+index**p
```

Nevertheless the output is not same list. I have tried to replace the inner loop with

```
for j in range(1,N+1):
    sums[N] = sums[N]+j**p
```

but this results to an index error message. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be due to the index difference. In Python, it starts from 0 while it's 1 in Matlab. Also, `sums = [0]*N` initialize a list of a length N, this has to be moved outside of the loop.

```
points = p+2
sums = [0]*points
for N in range(0, points):
    for index in range(0, N+1):
        sums[N] = sums[N] + (index+1)**p
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. Do you believe that the Python code could be written in a more pythonic way avoiding loops (using for instance list comprehension)?

Comment: Interesting question, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011078/what-does-pythonic-mean     One thing I would avoid is using sums for variable name, it is so similar to the function sum ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`sums(N) = 0;` does not create an array of all zeros, it sets element `N` of the existing array to 0, and creates additional elements in the array if it not at least of length `N`.

Because `N` grows by one each iteration, you could initialize as an empty array before the loop, and `append(0)` inside the loop:

```py
sums = []
for N in range(1, len(n)+1):
    sums.append(0)
```

I don’t particularly like the use of enumerate here either, I would:

```py
    for index in range(N)
        sums[index] += (index + 1)**p
```

(Notice the +1 on the index that was missing in the code in the OP!)

Finally, `n` is just confusing here. I would:

```
for N in range(1, points + 1):
    …
```