# Which import method in python is more pythonic

Tags: python, python-3.x

So when i code recently i saw the first method of importing sub-module, i usually use the 2nd one

```py
1. import PyQt6.QtWidgets as QtWidgets 
2. from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
```

Now i'm wondering which one is more pythonic?
I've tried reading at PEP 8 but didn't found the answer im looking for

Comment: From *my opinion*, I would chose the second as there's not repetition but I would assume you choose one or the other and stick with it for your project.

Comment: Both are pythonic. What does pythonic mean to you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011078/what-does-pythonic-mean