# Elegant slicing in python list based on index

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, list, numpy

I was wondering what would be an efficient an elegant way of slicing a python list based on the index. In order to provide a minimal example:

```
temp = ['a','b','c','d']

index_needed=[0,2]
```

How can I slice the list without the loop?

expected output

```
output_list =['a','c']
```

I have a sense that there would be a way but haven't figured out any. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: @JohnStark I don't think you have gone to the details of the question. I don't have a fixed start, stop or step params. I have an index list which I can use to slice it into two lists may be. Definitely not a duplicate

Comment: Please don't change the question once you have an answer. This means answerers and potential answers are looking at a moving target.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Picking out items from a python list which have specific indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724856/picking-out-items-from-a-python-list-which-have-specific-indexes)

Comment: Lists can only be indexed with a scalar or slice.  So some sort of iteration is required.  It's numpy arrays that can index with a list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, note that indexing in Python begins at 0. So the indices you need will be `[0, 2]`.

You can then use a list comprehension:

```
temp = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
idx = [0, 2]

res = [temp[i] for i in idx]            # ['a', 'c']
```

With built-ins, you may find `map` performs better:

```
res = map(temp.__getitem__, idx)        # ['a', 'c']
```

Since you are using Python 2.7, this returns a list. For Python 3.x, you would need to pass the `map` object to `list`.

---

If you are looking to avoid a Python-level loop altogether, you may wish to use a 3rd party library such as NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

temp = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
res = temp[idx]

# array(['a', 'c'], 
#       dtype='<U1')

res2 = np.delete(temp, idx)

# array(['b', 'd'], 
#       dtype='<U1')
```

This returns a NumPy array, which you can then be converted to a list via `res.tolist()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
temp = ['a','b','c','d']

temp[0:4:2]

#Output
['a', 'c']
```

Here first value is starting index number which is (Included) second value is ending index number which is (Excluded) and third value is (steps) to be taken.

Happy Learning...:)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that pushes the work to the C layer on CPython (the reference interpreter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

temp = ['a','b','c','d']

index_needed=[0,2]

output_list = itemgetter(*index_needed)(temp)
```

That returns `tuple` of the values; if `list` is necessary, just wrap in the `list` constructor:

```
output_list = list(itemgetter(*index_needed)(temp))
```

Note that this only works properly if you need at least two indices; `itemgetter` is variable return type based on how it's initialized, returning the value directly when it's passed a single key to pull, and a `tuple` of values when passed more than one key.

It's also not particularly efficient for one-off uses. A more common use case would be if you had an iterable of sequences (typically `tuple`s, but any sequence works), and don't care about them. For example, with an input `list` of:

```
allvalues = [(1, 2, 3, 4),
             (5, 6, 7, 8)]
```

if you only wanted the values from index 1 and 3, you could write a loop like:

```
for _, x, _, y in allvalues:
```

where you unpack all the values but send the ones you don't care about to `_` to indicate the lack of interest, or you can use `itemgetter` and `map` to strip them down to what you care about before the unpack:

```
from future_builtins import map  # Because Py2's map is terrible; not needed on Py3

for x, y in map(itemgetter(1, 3), allvalues):
```

The `itemgetter` based approach doesn't care if you have more than four items in a given element of `allvalues`, while manual unpacking would always require exactly four; which is better is largely based on your use case.